# How to compile FM-Index?

Tags: compiler-errors

I am trying to compile [FM-Index V2](http://pizzachili.di.unipi.it/indexes/FM-indexV2/), but get errors - both on Mac and on Linux:

```
make
make -C ./ds_ssort/; cp ./ds_ssort/ds_ssort.a .
make[1]: Entering directory `/storage1/maxwell/maasha/Install/src/fmindexV2/ds_ssort'
gcc -c -g -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -W -Wall -Winline -DDEBUG=0 -DNDEBUG=1   shallow.c -o shallow.o
shallow.c: In function ‘shallow_mkq’:
shallow.c:90: error: nested function ‘vecswap2’ declared but never defined
shallow.c: In function ‘shallow_mkq16’:
shallow.c:184: error: nested function ‘vecswap2’ declared but never defined
shallow.c: In function ‘shallow_mkq32’:
shallow.c:262: error: nested function ‘vecswap2’ declared but never defined
shallow.c: In function ‘shallow_inssort_lcp’:
shallow.c:496: error: nested function ‘cmp_unrolled_shallow_lcp’ declared but never defined
make[1]: *** [shallow.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/storage1/maxwell/maasha/Install/src/fmindexV2/ds_ssort'
cp: cannot stat `./ds_ssort/ds_ssort.a': No such file or directory
make: *** [ds_ssortr] Error 1
```

How to resolve this? The tarball is here:

http://pizzachili.di.unipi.it/indexes/FM-indexV2/fmindexV2.tgz

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this a while ago, so my recollection may be wrong, but I think FM-Index code uses functions defined in one of the other index codes. Take a look at [Run-Length FM Index](http://pizzachili.di.unipi.it/indexes/Run_Length_FM_index/). If it's not there, poke around somewhere else. I'm pretty sure the functions are defined somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the lines in the code that redeclared the functions. It worked for me.
After that, i had to edit the makefile and put the flag -lm to generate the executables.